# Are there common clients incapable of working with http headers?

Tags: rest, http-headers

I'm implementing a RESTful interface and in researching I regularly come across a mention that some clients can't work with HTTP headers so we need to provide the option to replicate the headers in the response body.

For example here: http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api?hn#envelope

I see this repeated everywhere yet I can't seem to find any specfic mention of clients that this would be a problem with.

Is this just repeated but outdated information or is it really an issue with modern clients?